# MsBuild: Forcing a rebuild when changing build configuration

Tags: msbuild

I have a `#if` in a project that depends on which build configuration is selected (eg: Debug, QA, and other test environments). When a user changes the build configuration in VS2015/Xamarin Studio, I need the IDE to force a rebuild on this project when the user builds the solution. How do I do this? At the moment, rebuilding the solution will reuse the compiled dll's.

In other words, how do I set a project `dirty` after a user changes the build configuration to force a rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the Output path of the project is unique to the build configuration. Otherwise MsBuild will just compare the timestamp of the input files and the existing output files and will conclude that a rebuild is not required.

It is assumed that when two projects build a different configuration, that they also write to a different folder for this reason.

Normally the output location is set to `.\bin\$(configuration)` to ensure this is the default behavior.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I accidentally copied the `Debug` build config but I didn't change the <OutputPath>.